# Windows 7: Edit group policy from command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, group-policy

I'm writing an installer and need to change the *All Users*' wallpaper. I can do this from the group policy editor GUI, but need to do so from my installer. I can't just edit the registry as it gets reset by a GPO on login.

How do I apply the relevant administrative template via programatically (preferably `cmd.exe` or via the registry)?
(for interest, it's `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop > Desktop > Desktop Wallpaper` [sic]

Comment: Regardless of how you set the wallpaper, the GP refresh will change it (back) if there's a policy set to do so. That's kind of the point. :)

Comment: Also take a look at this MS document: [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)

Answer (score 1):

are you in a domain environment? In that case, you will have to change your domain GPO.

Comment: Not an answer. I'm asking HOW (if possible) to change group policy. I don't happen to be in a domain environment. (But thank you.)